# Why aren't I getting bracket IntelliSense and related editing help in Visual Studio Code given my settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suppose I typed: `constructor() {}`, and I want to press Enter with a pointer between two brackets {}, and I assume the code will look like this, with multiple spaces at before an empty line:

```
constructor() {
  
}
```

But it's not, I get this one:

```
constructor() {
}
```

How can i adjust this with ts files? Or if it's possible, for all file types

I can't find information about this questions, I tried to turn on/off the different settings in the file->preferences->settings->brace(typing in the Search settings line)

this is my settings.json:

```json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons-darker",
  "dotnet.help.firstView": "gettingStarted",
  "extensions.confirmedUriHandlerExtensionIds": [
    "ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode",
    "ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-pack"
  ],
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
  "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "editor.language.brackets": [

  ],
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "sqltools.useNodeRuntime": true,
  "prettier.bracketSameLine": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "angular2-switcher.specFormats": [

    ".spec.ts",
    ".stories.ts"
  ],
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you did `"editor.language.brackets": []`. If you didn't mean to apply that setting, just remove that line. If you meant to set it only for a particular language, wrap that setting with a `[<lanugage>]: {}` block. If you meant to add to the brackets that normally are used for a language, you need to define also the brackets that are normally used by that language.

Related docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#brackets-definition.